# Object Reference Problem

Tags: c#, oop

I want to create t objects that refers to same reference but I want to change properties in the second one and don't change for the first one

```
student s=new student(10);

.........

student s2=new student(10);


s2.class="class2"
```

the question is to how can I know when I am at creating the seond student that I created instance before and if i created one before ,I will create new deep copy to avoid it

my proposal will be

```
{
student s=new student(10);

.........

if(we create any insatnce before from student)

student s2=cloneStudentMethod(10);
s2.class="class2"

}
```

and the `cloneStudentMethod(10)` create one deep copy object

the problem is how can I create this if condition ???

I hope that my problem is clear

Comment: I'm sorry it's still not very clear. You want to create a second instance as a copy of the first? Why not just create a distinct second instance? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not quite clear (to me). Could you more thoroughly explain what's wrong or undesirable about your current situation? I'm not getting why you need a deep copy, and what you're trying to "avoid".

Comment: I want to create it as a copy if I create one before and the problem how can I create this condition

Comment: It sounds like you either want to subclass student2 and add extra fields or make a seperate instance of student 2 which means it will NOT be the same object...

Comment: yes ,but I don't know if I create instance before or not . I cannot show my problem exactly but it I want to create new deep copy in case I created another one before

Comment: 1. explain if condition 2. explain the kind of object completely to deep copy or provide the code for Student class you want to deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to write a student factory which keeps track of that:

```
public class StudentFactory
{
    private HashSet<int> _CreatedIds = new HashSet<int>();
    public Student Create(int id)
    {
        _CreatedIds.Add(id);
        return new Student(id);
    }

    public bool HasCreatedStudentBefore(int id)
    {
         return _CreatedIds.Contains(id);
    }
}
```

**Update**: Instead of just putting the ids into the hashset you could store the students in there and return a copy of a student object if it is already in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some kind of clone method and do something like:

```
if (s != null)
{
student s2 = new Student();
s2.Clone(s);
}
```

This way you are passing the object you want to clone instead of just the single property (10 in your example).

I feel I don't quite understand your question, though.